# "Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object" when testing NestJS + TypeORM using Jest

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

I have a working NestJS server that performs some TypeORM `repository.insert()` command. However when running the same operation from a Jest test (using `@nestjs/testing`'s `Test.createTestingModule(...)`, the infamous `Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` appears.

Looking in more details, it appears that this is due to some dynamic loading occurring in TypeORM's `QueryBuilder`:

```
// loading it dynamically because of circular issue
const InsertQueryBuilderCls = require("./InsertQueryBuilder").InsertQueryBuilder;
```

That line succeeds when running the NestJS server but fails when running the Jest test. More specifically:

- in the NestJS server: QueryBuilder `require("./InsertQueryBuilder")` returns an ES module with a `InsertQueryBuilder` in it. When setting a breakpoint here, strangely the debugged file appears located at `src/query-builder/QueryBuilder.ts` (which is non-existent, and should rather be `node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/QueryBuilder.js`), but this succeeds.
- in the Jest test: `require("./InsertQueryBuilder")` return an empty object, and so `InsertQueryBuilder` is `undefined` which not an object indeed. The debugged file is as expected `node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/QueryBuilder.js`, but this fails.

I looks like it could be related to my Jest configuration, which is:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src']
}
```

as my Typescript sources are under a `src` directory under the project root. Those path issues are also be related to my `tsconfig.json`, which contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "target": "es2019",
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "incremental": true,
  "lib": [
    "es2019"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Also having this - did you solve this? If so, how?

Comment: @MartinGrönlund this has been discussed here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7086

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, there was no solution to be found there.